How to change property value of some components in livewire
So first of all that i'm new to livewire.
I have a livewire component called 'products-style', which contains a public variable called $productStyle, this varible can be changed by two buttons to either 'list' or 'block', and this variable is also being passed to several components inside this 'products-style' component, which are call 'product'.
I get the variable inside 'product' and i can use it, but it doesn't change in 'product' when it is changed in 'products-style'.
for example let's say we have 3 'product' components inside a 'products-style' component, and inside all of them we are displaying the $productStyle variable, which has the initial value of 'list' and it is inside the 'products-style' component. when we change the variable to 'block', all 'product' components should now display 'block' instead of 'list'... but they are still displaying 'list'.
in one sentence i mean the values are not synchronized!
this is how i'm passing the variable in 'products-style' component:
<livewire:product :$productStyle key="someKey" />

and this is the 'product-style' component class:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ProductsStyle extends Component
{
    public string $productStyle = '';

    public function setListStyle(): void
    {
        $this->productStyle = 'list';
    }

    public function setBlockStyle(): void
    {
        $this->productStyle = 'block';
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.products-style');
    }
}

and this is the 'product' component class:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Product extends Component
{
    public string $productStyle = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product');
    }
}

could someone please tell me the problem and how to solve it?

Why are you making it different components to begin with?

'product-style' will show all products but 'product' will only show a single product with different styles depending on $productStyle

By default in nested components, the passed variables are not reactive and you have to make them reactive!
You have to use #[Reactive] at the top of the variable in the child component class
in this case the code will be:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Attributes\Reactive;
use Livewire\Component;

class Product extends Component
{
    #[Reactive]
    public string $productStyle = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.product');
    }
}

